# Difference between "memory cache" and "memory pool"

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, memory-pool, memorycache

By reading "understanding linux network internals" and "understanding linux kernel" the two books as well as other references, I am quite confused and need some clarifications about the "memory cache" and ["memory pool"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) techniques.

1) Are they the same or different techniques?

2) If not the same, what makes the difference, or the distinct goals?

3) Also, how does the [Slab Allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) come in?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the slab allocator:

So imagine memory is flat that is you have a block of 4 gigs contiguous memory. Then one of your programs reqeuests a 256 bytes of memory so what the memory allocator has to do is choose a suitable block of 256 bytes from this 4 gigs. So now you your memory looks something like

<============256bytes=======================>

(each = is a contiguous block of memory). Some time passes and a lot of programs operating with the memory require more 256 blocks or more or less so in the end your memory might look like:

<==256==256=256=86=68=121===>

so it gets fragmented and then there is no trace of your beautiful 4gig block of memory - this is fragmentation. Now, what the slab allocator would do is keep track of allocated objects and once they are not used anymore it will say that the memory is free when in fact it will be retained in some sort of List (You might wanna read about [FreeLists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list)).

So now imagine that the first program relinquish the 256 bytes allocated and then a new would like to have 256 bytes so instead of allocating a new chunk of the main memory it might re-use the lastly freed 256 bytes without having to go through the burden of searching the physical memory for appropriate contiguous block of space. This is how you essentially implement the memory cache.  This is done so that memory fragmentation is reduced overall because you might end up in situation where memory is so fragmented that it is unusable and the memory-manager has to do some magic to get you block of appropriate size.  Where as using a slab allocator pro-actively combats (but doesn't eliminate) the problem.

Comment: thank you LordDoskias, for your input. However, that is more about fragmentation. It does not explain the same/diff relationship question I ask about "memory cache" and "memory pool".

Answer (score 0):

Linux memory allocator A.K.A slab allocator maintains the frequently used list/pool of memory objects of similar or approximate size. slab is giving extra flexibility to programmer to create their own pool of frequently used memory objects of same size and label it as programmer want,allocate, deallocate and finally destroy it.This cache is known to your driver and private to it.But there is a problem, during memory pressure there are high chances of allocation failures which could be not acceptable in some drivers, then what to do better always reserve some memory handy so that we never feel the memory crunch, since kmem cache is more generic pool mechanism we need some one who can always maintain  minimum required memory and that's our buddy memory pool .

Answer (score 0):

**Lookaside Caches** - The cache manager in the Linux kernel is sometimes called the *slab allocator*. You might end up allocating many objects of the same size over and over so by using this mechanism you just can allocate many objects in the same size and then use them later, without the need to allocate many objects over and over.

**Memory Pool** is just a form of lookaside cache that tries to always keep a list of memory around for use in emergencies, so when the memory pool is created, the allocation functions (*slab allocators*) create a pool of preallocated objects so you can acquire them when you need.